# Excel VBA - Completing another Loop Operation within a Do-While Loop

Tags: excel, vba, copy, do-while, paste

I'm currently learning VBA on my own from both trial and error, the macro recorder, and from reading/researching online. In most cases I'm able to find a work around to fill in the gaps. But in this case, I'm struggling a bit.

My issue is that my within my do-while loop, which opens (variable named workbooks), I need to then select a variable rowed, but static columned data set, then paste it into a model with a specified sheet.

I would like each workbook which is opened to run through the following steps:

1. find the last empty row of the active/opened workbook
2. copy that data
3. find the last empty row of the models specified sheet.

The issue is with the above step 3. While I have asked the code to find the last row, it seems to be "ignoring" this and pasting the data at A2 in the model.

What I've tried

1. I would like to avoid the used.range option as my source data each have headers on all workbooks, in previous testing I was unable to get the same range with used.range as I could with lastRow, lastColumn options.
2. using a byref, so that I could call the copied data - but i'm stuggling to understand how to use that even after reading up on it.
3. using wbSource and wbDest with specified ranges within the loop, I would like to avoid this unless it can be explained or a sample provided as to how this can be used in a loop as again I've been unable to get this to work.

   ```
   Sub GetAllFileNames()

   Dim Folder As String
   Dim FullFileName As String
   Dim FileStart As String
   Dim wbThis, wbSource As Workbook
   Dim lastRow As Long
   Dim wshtDest As Worksheet

   Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
   Set wshtDest = wbThis.Sheets("Report")
   lastRow = wshtDest.Cells(wshtDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(lastRow).row + 1
   'rlastRow = ReportSht.Cells(ReportSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(lastRow).row

   Folder = Sheet1.Range("C7") & "\"

   FileStart = "D1*"
   FullFileName = Dir(Folder & FileStart)

   On Error Resume Next
   Do While FullFileName <> ""

       Workbooks.Open Folder & FullFileName
       Call source_rng
       For Each copied_rng In Selection
           With wshtDest
           .Activate
           .Cells(lastRow, 1).Select
           .PasteSpecial
           End With
       Next copied_rng
   '    wshtDest.Range("A" & rlastRow).Offset(1).Select
       Debug.Print lastRow
       Debug.Print FullFileName
       FullFileName = Dir() ' moves to next file
       DoEvents     'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Loop

   End Sub


   Sub source_rng()

   Dim sht As Worksheet
   Dim lastRow, lastColumn As Long
   Dim StartCell, copied_rng As Range

   Set sht = ActiveSheet
   Set StartCell = Range("A2")

   'Find Last Row and Column
     lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).row
     lastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   'Select Range
   sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Copy

   End Sub
   ```

Currently, the above code does not produce any errors, however when the loop is removed and 1 spreadsheet is opened and copy and pasted into the model, the lastRow lookup in the model works perfectly.

However, when the loop is put into place, each opened workbook's data is copied at A2 in the model, where it should find the next empty row and paste the source data at that point.

Comment: put this code's line under `With wshtDest`: `lastRow = .Cells(wshtDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(lastRow).row + 1`.

You always got 'A2' because you didn't update your `lastRow` after paste

Comment: Thanks @gaback - that sorted it, however the lastRow code also needed tweeking to:  `lastRow = .Cells(wshtDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row`  --- otherwise it never went back to the end of the model's data :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You did a nice job in compiling your question. I'd just advise you to always make efforts to have your question clear at the end. What you need has to be clearly seen at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you define `lastrow` outside of the loop. This means that it gets filled 1 time (probably as row 2), and never updated. You would have to recalculate it for each iteration of your for loop.

So something like this:

```
    For Each copied_rng In Selection
        lastRow = wshtDest.Cells(wshtDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
        With wshtDest
        .Activate
        .Cells(lastRow, 1).Select
        .PasteSpecial
        End With
    Next copied_rng
```

Since you said you were still learning; there is a way to check whether your variables are filled with the values you would expect. You could step through your code using F8 and track them in the Watch window: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/debugging/watch-window.htm

Hope that helps.

Comment: oh my lord...i didn't even think of that!! I was using debug.print lastRow to see what it did, but as it was working fine when i opened a single spreadsheet, it wasn't make sense! I will run with code with the lastRow inside the loop and see if that helps. *brb*

Comment: after some trial and error this worked like a charm! Please note that the correct answer is slightly different from your answer @beek - see below is the correct answer :)
<!-- language: lang-none -->
    `For Each copied_rng In Selection
        lastRow = wshtDest.Cells(wshtDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
        With wshtDest
        .Activate
        .Cells(lastRow, 1).Select
        .PasteSpecial
        'End With'
    Next copied_rng`

Comment: I think both would do the trick. Yours finds the last row and uses and offset of 1 row, mine finds the last row and adds 1 to the rownumber. But anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: Oh apologies! thats what I get for speed reading! I didn't realise you took out the `offset(lastRow)` part from my original code.